# NSURLConnection multiple asynchronous connections

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I am trying to figure out why my UI doesnt update until after ALL of my NSURLConnections have loaded.

I am basically loading one "login" request, receiving the response, and calling:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionFinishedLoading" object:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dataForConnection forKey:conn.tag]]
```

I receive the notification elsewhere in my code, and it calls:

```
[self.loginViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

along with an NSLog, so I know its actually getting to this method at the right time, its just that the view controller isnt being dismissed until after other NSURLConnections which basically get started at the same time as the dialog is hidden have finished.

I have been researching this for the last few hours, and I am still unsure whether the code I am using to create/send the requests is working asynchronously or not:

```
-(void)initGET:(NSString *)url queryString:(NSString *)theQueryString tag:(NSString *)tag{
if([Utils CanConnectToURL:url]){
    //NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
    //NSLog(@"queryString: %@", theQueryString);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", url, theQueryString]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60*10];
    URLConnection *connection = [[URLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES tag:tag];
    if(connection){
        [receivedData setObject:[NSMutableData data] forKey:connection.tag];
        [conns addObject:connection];
    }
    else
        [receivedData setObject:NSLocalizedString(@"ConnectionError", nil) forKey:connection.tag];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NoInternetConnectionTitle", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"NoInternetConnectionMessage", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.tag = 999;
    [alert show];
}
```

}

My guess is that it is already asyncronous, as I start 3 other NSURLConnections directly after the 1st one has finished, and my logs show that the 3 other connections are all starting as basically the same time, and then all completing later. If it was only synchronous, surely, 1 connection would start, then finish, then the 2nd connection start/finish and so on...

Does any body know why my UI could not be updating properly? and if so, what a good workaround would be - ive already had a bit of a look at NSOperationQueue, but using this seems to start causing other problems when passing messages/objects out using NSNotificationCenter, which I use quite a bit in my URLConnectionManager class.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

URLConnection isn't a standard NSURLConnection. It's difficult to tell if it's asynchronous without seeing the implementation of URLConnection.

Also, how are you updating your UI when you're notified that the connection has finished?

Comment: Hi - URLConnection is a subclass of NSURLConnection, and i only do it so i can attach a "tag" property to the object: 
//URLConnection.m -(id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately tag:(NSString *)theTag{
    self.tag = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:theTag];
 self = [super initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:YES];
 return self;
} I am also updating the UI by hiding a modally presented view controller, but it isnt actually hiding until all requests have loaded